# Copy Rows from a Sheet to another sheet based on Criteria

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am using Gdocs spreadsheet for jobs queue.

I would like to know how a row and all its content (from column A:AS) can be moved from "Live WIP Jobs" (sheet1) Tab to "Delivered Jobs" (Sheet2) Tab by marking it as "Delivered" in Column "AP".

Normally it will be marked as WIP in sheet1.

On marking it as Delivered, I would like the row to copied to the Sheet2 and get it removed from sheet1.

Attaching sheet for reference

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gZYni8SGUa4Ohu3BIOxJh2bQSUqQh_5Q3epDidP574E/edit#gid=1557156093

I also tried the below script.. but it wasn't working and fetching error:

```
function CopyRowsOnConditions() {

  // assumes source data in sheet named Live WIP Jobs

  // target sheet of move to named Delivered

  // test column with Delivered/WIP is col AP or 42

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 

  var numRows = sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows(); 

  var source = sheet.getRange(2, 42, numRows); 

  if(s.getName() == "Live WIP Jobs" && r.getColumn() == 42 && r.getValue() == "Delivered"){
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Delivered");

    if(targetSheet.getLastRow() == targetSheet.getMaxRows()) {
      targetSheet.insertRowsAfter(targetSheet.getLastRow(), 20); //inserts 20 rows after last used row
    }

    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);

    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking the code in the script (the one you posted was not complete) i noticed that you are creating the variables "r" and "s" using the variable "event".

When you have a event (eg. onEdit) the function receives a parameter event, then you can us it. here is information in those events https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

If you are going to use an event, change the code accordingly, as mention in the documentation.